# Getting the information shown in the facebook recommendation plugin on my website

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After implementing the facebook recommendation plugin on my website, the user gets a personalized experience wherein all the pages liked on my website are sorted based on his/her social graph. I want to access the personalized ordering of the links as the user sees and show them in my android application.

- Is there a direct way to integrate/implement the facebook recommendation plugin into android application?

  1. If no, can I read this information using my appId, if the user is logged into facebook?
  2. Do I need to create an application and have the user authenticate it before accessing the information? If so how?

Any pointers would be life-saving.

Cheerio!
- Maliha.